# PyTorch Tensor methods to nn.Modules?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm programming some callable custom modules in PyTorch and I wanted to know if I'm doing it correctly. Here's an example scenario where I want to construct a module that takes a `torch.Tensor` as input, performs a learnable linear operation and outputs a diagonal covariance matrix to use in a multivariate distribution downstream.

```
class Exp(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return x.exp()

class Diag(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return x.diag_embed()

def init_model(input_size, output_size):
    log_variance_module = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)
    diag_covariance_module = nn.Sequential(logvar_module, Exp(), Diag())
    return diag_covariance_module

model = init_model(5, 5)
cov = model(some_input_tensor)
dist = MultivariateNormal(some_mean, cov)
```

I know that this works, but is it the right design pattern? How is one recommended to approach these modules?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the correct design pattern.

Ideally, you would also write your main network as an `nn.Module`:

```
class Model(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        logvar_module = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)
        super().__init__(logvar_module, Exp(), Diag())
```